# Android NullPointerException in OnCreate method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I have been writing this Android application for the past few days and everything has been working smoothly, until today. In my app I was trying to implement a tabbed view for my application, but as soon as I try to run it my application installs and force closes immediately upon opening. I have been sitting at this for an entire day and cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Hopefully someone can help me out.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
{com.stullich.tim.lolbufftimer/com.stullich.tim.lolbufftimer.LoLBuffTimerMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(5469):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:1573) 
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:907)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at com.stullich.tim.lolbufftimer.LoLBuffTimerMain.<init>(LoLBuffTimerMain.java:14)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
E/AndroidRuntime(5469):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the code for the main activity:

```
public class LoLBuffTimerMain extends TabActivity{

Resources res = getResources(); 
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourBuffs.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("yourbuffs").setIndicator("Your Buffs", 
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_view_you))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, EnemyBuffs.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("enemybuffs").setIndicator("Enemy Buffs", 
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_view_enemy))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">        
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack trace points to this line as the source of the exception:

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

The inherited `getResources()` method is throwing an exception. That's because you can't call `getResources()` until later, after the activity is constructed and initialized. Move those member variable initializations into `onCreate()` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines need to be defined inside onCreate

```
Resources res = getResources(); 
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this, but I think you can do a `getTabHost()` only after you do a `setContentView()`. Otherwise getTabHost() returns null (this behavior is similar to `findViewById()`).